# develop a n-tier application in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to build ntier application in sharepoint. Can any of you share your code with me? I would like to see how ntire applications can be created in sharepoint.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this series of articles can help you get up to speed? http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/sharedove-architecture-project/

Best

Dragan

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special in my opinion about it. If it's custom code, it's just applying the principles of n-tier architecture. You may want to go across to the fundamentals of n-tier.